# Set String To "" In A LINQ Query Where NULL

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following query, sometimes `ExpirationDate` is null which blows up the query and the application crashes. If `ExpirationDate` is null I want to return `""` for `ExpirationDate`. How do I put this if condition in LINQ?

```
List<PData> pressData = 
    (from press in dataContext.CPress
        where press.ID.ToString() == this.PressID
        select new PData
        {
            Heading = press.Heading,
            Description = press.MetaDescription,
            DatePublished = press.PublishDate.ToShortDateString(),
            ExpirationDate = press.ExpirationDate.Value.ToShortDateString(),
            Body = press.BodyContent,

            CreatedBy=press.CreatedBy
        }).ToList();
```

UPDATE :

Adding the code Jon suggested I get the following exception

> ```
> Could not translate expression 'Table(CPress).Where(press =>
> ```
>
> (press.PressID.ToString() =
>   Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.String])))).Select(press
>   => new PData() {Heading = press.Heading, Description =
>   press.MetaDescription, DatePublished =
>   press.PublishDate.ToShortDateString(),
>   ExpirationDate =
>   IIF((press.ExpirationDate = null), "",
>   press.ExpirationDate.Value.ToShortDateString()),
>   Body = press.BodyContent, ID =
>   press.PressID, CreatedBy =
>   press.CreatedBy})' into SQL and could
>   not treat it as a local expression.

Taking ExpirationDate out totally the exception goes away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it doesn't answer you question directly, but...

If possible, I would keep the date as `DateTime?`.  Usually you want to format it (`ToShortDateString()`, etc.) whenever you display it, not before.

**Edit:** Similarly in `where press.ID.ToString() == this.PressID`: `this.PressID` would ideally match the type of `press.ID`.  Really, the language is strongly-typed for a reason.  If you make all your variables strings, it defeats the whole purpose.

Of course there are some *unusual* circumstances where you might have to do this and yours may be one of them, but I see no indication that is the case.

Comment: I am using binding syntax to bind the value to a control. How do I use binding syntax on something of type DateTime?

Comment: Text=' <%# Eval("ExpirationDate")%>'

Comment: @Nick: You can specify a format string.  For example: `<%# Eval("ExpirationDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>`

Comment: @Nick: Here are the different formatting options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx  On the left menu you can drill into the standard and custom DateTime options.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use:

```
ExpirationDate = press.ExpirationDate == null ? "":
                        press.ExpirationDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
```

EDIT: Having said that, it will only work around the immediate problem. I agree with Nelson's approach of keeping it as a `DateTime?` and performing the conversion at display time. Aside from anything else, that means you can apply the appropriate culture information etc for the user at that point.

Comment: is it legal to use if then syntax instead of the shorthand?

Comment: @Nick: Not if this is going to be converted to an expression tree, no.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd go for the option that @Jon Skeet has suggested, but an alternative if you don't like the syntax is to write an extension method and call that

```
public static string ToShortDateStringOrEmpty(this DateTime? dt)
{
    if (dt == null)
        return String.Empty;
    else
        return dt.ToShortDateString();
}
```

This has the advantage of being neater if you're doing a complex query (such as if the order isn't null, show me the sum of all the line items) and traversing a lot of objects.

Comment: That won't work for LINQ to SQL etc though, as it won't know about it.

Comment: That's true, you'd have to have an AsEnumerable on the previous return if you wanted to do that but then you'd have all of the data on the client instead of the server.